# Server.MapPath() not getting specific folder

Tags: asp.net, web-services, server.mappath

i am trying to save an image file in my WebApplication folder but its not working
Here is the directory map

```
wwwroot
  -
  -
  -----RegApp
  -      -
  -      ----Images
  -
  -
  -----RegService
```

i am saving file from `WebService(RegService)` into `WebApp(RegApp)` directory
Here is the code from WebService

```
File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("../RegApp//Images//" + Email + ".jpeg"), Convert.FromBase64String(PictureByteString));
```

but it gives me this

```
System.Web.HttpException: Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.
   at System.Web.Util.UrlPath.ReduceVirtualPath(String path)
   at System.Web.Util.UrlPath.Reduce(String path)
   at System.Web.Util.UrlPath.Combine(String appPath, String basepath, String relative)
   at System.Web.VirtualPath.Combine(VirtualPath relativePath)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, VirtualPath baseVirtualDir, Boolean allowCrossAppMapping)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.MapPath(String path)
```

Comment: RegApp is **above** RegService folder, default IIS settings does not allow to access a folder above site root folder. Change your ISS settings or...your design. Imagine if a malicious request will go to "..\..\windows\system32\something..."

Comment: then whats the solution ? i am saving pictures from Android via webservice and showing via WebApp. how can i make these images available for WebApp ?

Comment: `Server.MapPath("RegApp\Images\" + Email + ".jpeg")` will work?

Comment: Relax IIS settings or (better, IMO) use your web service to both store and retrieve that images (you don't need to expose methods for that, simply refer to web service URL to access them). You may even expose a POST page in your web app to UPLOAD images (from web service). Again you may store them in another place and give proper rights for access.

Comment: @Bharadwaj : no it didn't worked i have already checked it..

Answer (score 0):

I guess problem is with using "../" in MapPath, a workaround is to call MapPath("."), then use System.IO classes to go wherever you want.

```
string baseDir = Server.MapPath(".");
string imageName = Directory.GetParent(baseDir).FullName + "/RegApp//Images//" + Email + ".jpeg";

File.WriteAllBytes(imageName, Convert.FromBase64String(PictureByteString));
```

Another solution, is to put the physical directory location stored in a config key, and ditch MapPath entirely.

You have to have access to the directory in both cases.

Comment: its looking for \RegService\RegApp\Images\email@mail.com.jpeg'.

Comment: when i used a physical path like C:\Images, the WebApp starts looking in client's C: drive for images...

Comment: Ok, this is a server side web app, it will not look at the "client's" C drive! What did Server.MapPath(".") return?

Comment: C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\RegService

Comment: Good, the code I posted will navigate a step above "Directory.GetParent()", and append "RegApp/Images" and your email value. which is what you need. and call "File.WriteAllBytes" to your new destination (C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\RegApp\Images\{email}.jpg).
isn't this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a easy way by using **Virtual Directory**.. Now i am using `C:\Images` folder of server to store them images via `webService` and added that Images folder to `WebApp` as virtual folder so what ever is stored in `C:\Images` folder is available in `WebApp\Images` folder...